# Cast variable as an ItemSource for a LongListViewer

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have a variable named `items` that finds a set of descendants of an XML element and binds them to a `TextBlock` on a `LongListViewer` in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. When I go and try to set the `ItemSource` with this variable, it comes up with an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Lists.ListsXmlBinder>` to
>   `System.Collections.IList`. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Here is my code:

```
using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (Stream stream = storage.CreateFile("list.xml"))
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(stream);
        document.Element("lists").Add(new XElement("list", new XElement("name", "random list"), new XElement("date", DateTime.Now.ToString())));
        document.Save(stream);

        var items = from query in document.Descendants("list")
                    select new ListsXmlBinder
                    {
                        Name = query.Element("name").Value,
                        Date = query.Element("date").Value
                    };

        lists_ListViewer.ItemsSource =  items;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a call to [ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the `IEnumerable` to a list:

```
var items = (from query in document.Descendants("list")
                            select new ListsXmlBinder
                            {
                                Name = query.Element("name").Value,
                                Date = query.Element("date").Value
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you sstan for the response. It is highly appreciative of you.